# Why does pywinauto have 10 second delays between commands?

Tags: python, pywinauto

This code has a 10 second delay between iterations:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=19840)
dlg = app.windows()
for i in range(lbitemcount):
    i += 1
    rselitem = "ListItem" + str(i)
    lditemtext = str(app.dlg.ListBox.child_window(best_match=""+rselitem+"").texts())
    print(homenum, lditemtext)
    if homenum == lditemtext:
        app.dlg.ListBox.child_window(best_match=""+rselitem+"").double_click_input()
        break
```

Other `pywinauto` commands seem to have the same issue (such as input or getting text from textboxes). How can I reduce this delay?

Comment: Try to measure iteration time with `app.dlg.ListBox.wrapper_object()` when getting `lditemtext` value. It may help to localize the problem. If the problem is in `child_window(best_match=""+rselitem+"")`, try to use another locator using `control_type`, `title_re` or other keywords. They are much faster than `best_match` search.

Comment: I optimised my code, but timing are so slow for 2 commands

`from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=24764)

dlg = app.windows()

app.dlg.ListBox.child_window(title="" + building + "").double_click_input()`


and this is timings

connect to app - 7.335336685180664

select - 7.866688966751099

Comment: `connect` should be fast. Try to exclude `ListBox` from `app.dlg.ListBox.child_window` chain. 2 levels of search is enough. `ListBox` attribute means "child_window(best_match="ListBox")` at second level. Third level of search can become 2nd level then.

Comment: Also I think `dlg = app.windows()` is incorrect. It should be Python list of `UIAWrapper`s. But you use it below as WindowSpecification object. Please re-check your code in the question and edit it if necessary.